# Dragging li element and dropping it in the div element in d3

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I'm having a little trouble getting this concept started. I generate this data from a JSON file that looks like this

```
{
  "nodes": [
    {"container": "1", "x" : 0, "y" : 0, "height" : 100, "width" : 100, "sample": "sample1"},
    {"container": "2", "x" : 200, "y" : 0, "height" : 100, "width" : 100, "sample": "sample5"},
    {"container": "3", "x" : 400, "y" : 0, "height" : 100, "width" : 100, "sample": "sample4"}
    ]

 "samples" : [
    {"id" : "Sample 1"},
    {"id" : "Sample 2"},
    {"id" : "Sample 3"}
    ]
}
```

The data is represented currently like this

[image: Image of the entire code]

On the left side is the container  elements that have been generated from the data and on the right side is a  element that has

elements inside that correspond to each of the Samples from the JSON file. My goal is to get the

element from the div on the right side and drag it into any of the containers. So far I have had no getting this to work.

**The Code**

There is a helper function that is used as a shadow to dictate where the containers are in the drag function and it works for the containers but not the samples

The drag functions:

```
 var drag = d3.behavior.drag().origin(Object);
 function createHelper(x, y){
            helper = grid.selectAll('.helper').data([{}]).enter().insert('div', ":first-child")
                .attr('class', 'helper')
                .style('left', function(d){d.x = x; return d.x + 'px'})
                .style('top', function(d){d.y = y; return d.y + 'px'})
                .style('width', function(d){d.width = wBlob; return d.width + 'px'})
                .style('height', function(d){d.height = hBlob; return d.height + 'px'})
                .style("background-color", "black")
                .style("opacity", ".3")
                .style("padding", "1.5em")
                .style("position", "absolute");
        }

        drag.on('dragstart', function(d){
            if (helper) helper.remove();
            createHelper(d.x, d.y);

        });

        drag.on('dragend', function(d){
            var hx = helper.datum().x;
            var hy = helper.datum().y;
            d.x = hx;
            d.y = hy;
            d3.select(this).transition().duration(100).style('left', d.x + 'px').style('top', d.y + 'px')
                .each('end', function(){helper.remove();});

        });

        drag.on('drag', function(d,i){
            var x = d3.event.x;
            var y = d3.event.y;
            d.x = x;
            d.y = y;
            var hx =  Math.round((d.x)/100)*100;
            var hy =  Math.round((d.y)/100)*100;
            helper.datum().x = hx;
            helper.datum().y = hy;

            d3.select(this).style('left', d.x + 'px').style('top', d.y + 'px');
            helper.style('left', hx + 'px').style('top', hy + 'px');
        });
```

And the function for the samples generated on the side

```
samples = sidebar
            .selectAll("div")
            .data(data.samples)
            .enter()
            .append("li")
            .style("display", "inline-block")
            .style("grid-column", "5")
            .style("width", "100px")
            .style("height", "40px")
            .style("margin", "0 0 0 0")
            .style("list-style", "none")
            .style("text-align", "center")
            .style("padding", ".5rem")
            .style("border", "3px #7f7f7f solid")
            .style("box-sizing", "border-box")
            .style("font-family", ".8rem/1 arial, helvetica, sans-serif")
            .text(function(d, i) {
                return d.id;
            })
            .on('contextmenu', function () {
                d3.event.preventDefault()
            }).call(drag);
```

So I am a beginner at d3 just been learning this week in jQuery there is the drag and droppable functions that are not too bad to implement and been looking for an effective way to do this in d3.

Comment: Why are you setting the `drag.origin` to "Object"?  [Remove that and your code starts to work](http://plnkr.co/edit/0YM8hrApqHvKwUXqDVPY?p=preview)